# Declare enum by value from properties file

Tags: spring, spring-boot, enums

I have property file (application.yml) like this:

```
userID:
 limitedAttempts:
 -
  bins:
  - "123456"
  attempts: 2
  bookType: ALPHA
 -
  bins:
  - "789012"
  attempts: 2
  bookType: NHANAM
```

And class for properties:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "userID")
@RefreshScope
public class UserIDProperties {
    private List<LimitedAttempt> limitedAttempts = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
    public static class LimitedAttempt{
        private List<String> bins = new ArrayList<>();
        private int attempts;
        private BookType bookType;
        ...
    }
}
```

How can I declare BookType as enum with value from property file: ALPHA, NHANAM

In case I update property file by addition new element, such as:

```
userID:
 limitedAttempts:
 -
  bins:
  - "123456"
  attempts: 2
  bookType: ALPHA
 -
  bins:
  - "789012"
  attempts: 2
  bookType: NHANAM
 -
  bins:
  - "456789"
  attempts: 2
  bookType: FIRSTNEW
```

rebuild project, the BookType will be: ALPHA, NHANAM, FIRSTNEW.
Can I do that?

*note: I can declare BookType as java

```
public enum BookType{
    ALPHA,
    NHANAM;
}
```

but it not dynamic, because I use consul, so I don't want to update in java code.
Thank for your help.

Comment: why use enum, when you can just define `BookType` as a class?

Comment: I would like to avoid to send data to mobile devices that can't be handled in current mobile builds.
Currently mobile devices can process ALPHA & NHANAM only and we should be sure that we don't send new book types before they can process it.

Comment: @LocLe Did you solve this?